# onBackPressed never gets called

Tags: android

I have a problem with these functions. I want to override the native back button, but the functions never get called and I don't understand where it's the mistake.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) 
    { //Back key pressed
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity2.class);
        startActivity(in);
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

public void onBackPressed()
{
    mCountDownTimer.cancel();
    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity2.class);
    startActivity(in);

    return;
}// end of onBackpressed
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown

Comment: You don't need both. Just do `onBackPressed`.

Comment: Add @Override annotation to onBackPressed() if at all you are missing it.

Comment: You can override this method in Activity first of all check your onBackPressed is inside some Activity.

Comment: Yes, I have the annotation and it is inside an Activity. But it still doesn't work. I would like to stop the timer when I press that button, but it doesn't do that, and every time I enter on this activity, a new timer is launched. I don't know where to cancel it.

Comment: can you please paste your activity code here, there is no need of using onKeyDown for getting back button event you can just override onBackPressed().

Comment: I've posted all the code from this activity. thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    mCountDownTimer.cancel();
    Intent in = new Intent(this, MyActivity2.class);
    startActivity(in);

    super.onBackPressed();

}// end of onBackpressed
```

Comment: I've already tried this, it doesn't work...:( thanx :)

Comment: can you comment out other code like : public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{ }

Comment: It still doesn't work